# Grab Authenticated NTLM Username from IIS

Tags: go, iis, ntlm

I have a Go Web service/test API running as an IIS website. I set it up following these directions on this website and it runs great.

https://medium.com/@mossila/running-go-behind-iis-ce1a610116df.

Only thing I had to change was using AspNetCoreModuleV2 instead of AspNetCoreModule.

My API is just one minor function that receives Post data and assigns it to a struct.

```
func (app *App) ReadPostData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var payloadData postPayload

    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&payloadData)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf(payloadData.ID)
}
```

Now, because it's running on IIS, I can switch on Windows Auth mode(NTLM) and make the web service require NLTM auth to access.

The question becomes, is there a GOOD way to pass the NTLM auth username to the test API I've written in Go? In PHP on IIS I could just do $_SERVER["AUTH_USER"]; and it would automatically set that authenticated username as a variable, is there an equivalent of this in Go?

Comment: Using ASP.NET Core module for anything other than ASP.NET Core is subject to failures. Microsoft won't support you on that. HttpPlatformHandler is your only option. BTW, for a cross platform Go application, you shouldn't use anything Windows specific like Windows authentication.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Few questions for you.

#1. What failures can one expect when using ASP.NET Core over HttpPlatformHandler? I thought HttpPlatformHandler was replaced by ASP.NET Core...or am I totally wrong?

#2. The only reason I even need the username is because my backend API calls a SQL stored procedure for INSERT. I need to track who did what in the DB.

Thanks for all your help, just trying to understand more what my options are.

Comment: The actual "replaced by" is under the context of ASP.NET Core, https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/105. ASP.NET Core module is strictly a module for ASP.NET Core web apps, where HttpPlatformHandler cannot work well enough with, and you can learn from its documentation that Microsoft never expects it to work with anything else (like Go), https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1 No way to say what failures might happen but using the wrong thing is always bad. To get user name you can use other authentication methods.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again for all your help.